# Using Selenium webdriver with a For Loop

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, webdriver

I am attempting to write a for loop to select product UPC's on a website.  Essentially I have a list of UPC's in an Excel file that I want to loop through to EITHER: (1) Find the item through the search bar and select it OR (2) Item is not found and I want to add it to a list of Not Found UPCs.  This is where I am at so far.  I am unsure if I should use an IF ELSE statement or something else.  I would really appreciate any thoughts or guidance.

```
for upc in upc_list:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath for search bar').clear()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath for search bar').send_keys(upc)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="'+upc+'"]'))).click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the element is not found an exception will be thrown and you have to catch it with a `try` `except`

```
upc_list=[]
not_found_list=[]
for upc in upc_list:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath for search bar').clear()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath for search bar').send_keys(upc)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="'+upc+'"]'))).click()
    except:
        print('no results for '+upc)
        not_found_list.append(upc)
        continue
    print('results for '+upc)
    # utc is found
    # do what ever you want with it
```

Comment: Thank you!!  That works great.  As a follow-up, the website does come back with a "No data was found" message when a UPC is not found.  Is there a way to use that message to speed up the code?  e.g. IF UPC is found .click() that UPC, IF 'No data was found' appears then append to not_found_list  and continue.  I would like to leave the WebDriverWait at 10 since sometimes the search does take a little time, but currently that means every not found UPC will take that long before the loop continues.  You've already helped so much, but if you have any ideas, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: one thing you could do is chick if the response is 404 if no data was found, you can tell from the network tab in the dev tools of the browse, then you could continue the loop if response code is not 200... if its always 200, you can deploy a second ```webdriver.find_element``` to look for the "not found" message, when found just skip the look for upc.